# Combining Multiple Files in TypeScript except Initialization Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

Hi I tried to combine multiple typescript files with AMD Module

My tsconfig.js looks like this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile" : "build.js"
    },
    "files" : [
        "./common/component.ts",
        "./common/button.ts",
        "./project/init.ts",
        "./project/app.ts",
        "./project/menu.ts"
    ]
}
```

But i am not getting what i want because my initialize code is also defined inside the module (Below)

```
define("project/app", ["require", "exports", "common/component", "project/menu"], function (require, exports, component_3, menu_1) {
    "use strict";
    var App = (function (_super) {
        __extends(App, _super);
        function App(root) {
            _super.call(this);
            this.root = root;
        }
        App.prototype.decorate = function () {
            this.menu = new menu_1.Menu(document.getElementById("menu"));
        };
        App.prototype.bindEvent = function () {
            //no event to bind
        };
        App.prototype.detach = function () {
            this.menu = null;
        };
        App.prototype.unbindEvent = function () {
            // no event to unbind
        };
        return App;
    }(component_3.Component));
    exports.App = App;
});
define("project/init", ["require", "exports", "project/app"], function (require, exports, app_1) {
    "use strict";
    var root = document.getElementById("html");
    var app = new app_1.App(root);
});
```

In the figure above, i don't want the project/init is defined inside the define function. Because if it is, then no code will be executed.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that's correct behavior. If you package it as AMD modules, then everything is a module and it's up to you and your module loader to decide which module to run first.

Comment: how to decide which module to run first?

Comment: That's what you have to decide, not the module loader. In your case I guess you want to load `project/init` which loads the rest.

Comment: how to do it? yes, i want to run project/init first

Comment: Use a module loader such as SystemJS.